# Similar Char(TCS CodeVita) Reduce Time Complexity

Tags: c++

You have to take the length of the string from the user then input the string from the user, after that take the no. of queries from the user to check. Suppose that the user gives 3 queries 4,5,7. Then 4,5,7 are the position where you have to check how many of the same characters are repeated before that position.

Inputs:

1. 9 (Length of the string to input)
2. abcabcabc
3. 3 (No. of queries to check)
4. 4 (Check at position 4)
5. 5 (Check at position 5)
6. 7 (Check at position 7)

Output:

1. 1
2. 1
3. 2

**Code which I made:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n; // Length of String
    int a[10000]; // Input for Query
    int q; // NO. of queries
    std::cin >> n;
    char ch[n]; // To store the InputString

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        std::cin >> ch[i];
    }

    std::cin >> q;

    for (int j = 1; j <= q; j++) {
        std::cin >> a[j];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= q; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < a[i]; j++) {
            if (ch[j] == ch[a[i]]) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << count << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is this the time complexity of the program is too much.In worst case it would be **O(n*q)**, where n = length of the string and q = number of queries. How to improve the time complexity?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can help you with programming problems if they are specific, but "please rewrite it" is too broad.

Comment: Add current time complexity, ask how to improve?

Answer (score 0):

First, your Output does not meet the assignment. For example, at the position `[1]`, there is character `'b'` (0-based indexing), which has **zero** repetitions **before** that position. At the position `[2]`, there is character `'a'`, which has one repetition before that position. So do you mean, **before, including**?

Second, is that a [homework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework)? (Just curious. Can hardly imagine any real-life case here... :))

Finally, to your question:

1) make an array of `<query position, count>` pairs

2) go through the `InputString` **only once** up to the highest `query position` and at every position in the `InputString`, increase your `count` if relevant for the `query position` in the `<query position, count>` pair.

2.b) Slight further optimization: sort your array or `<query position, count>` pairs according to the `query position` first. In your `InputString`, go to the **lowest** `query position` so that you have to check for every `<query position, count>` pair in this first turn. Then continue searching your `InputString` from the [lowest `query position` + 1] position up to the second lowest `query position`. You do not need to care about the lowest `<query position, count>` pair in this second turn. Etc. ...